# MYSQL query faster

Tags: mysql, performance

How can I make this query faster? It just a way to select fields where you can input varchar text.

```
    SELECT
        F.field_name,
        FI.farmer_name,
        FI.lname_farmer,
        FI.farmer_email,
        FI.farmer_group,
        L.first_name,
        L.last_name,
        L.email,
        EI.extension_name,
        EI.lname_ext,
        EI.other_prof,
        EI.extension_name
    FROM
        anReference AS R
    INNER JOIN anFieldInfo AS F ON R.ref_id = F.ref_id
    INNER JOIN anFarmerInfo AS FI ON F.ref_id = R.ref_id
    INNER JOIN anCropInfo AS C ON C.ref_id = R.ref_id
    INNER JOIN anLocalTechnician AS L ON L.ref_id = R.ref_id
    INNER JOIN anSessionExtension AS SE ON SE.ref_id = R.ref_id
    INNER JOIN anExtensionInfo AS EI ON EI.extension_id = SE.extension_id
    where   R.date_accessed BETWEEN '2016-03-20 00:00:00'
AND NOW() AND (
            F.field_name LIKE '%test%'
            OR FI.farmer_name LIKE '%test%'
            OR FI.lname_farmer LIKE '%test%'
            OR FI.farmer_email LIKE '%test%'
            OR FI.farmer_group LIKE '%test%'
            OR L.first_name LIKE '%test%'
            OR L.last_name LIKE '%test%'
            OR L.email LIKE '%test%'
            OR EI.extension_name LIKE '%test%'
            OR EI.lname_ext LIKE '%test%'
            OR EI.other_prof LIKE '%test%'
            OR EI.extension_name LIKE '%test%'
        ) AND r.category = 0;
```

I already tried using concat but it has no to little effect.

Comment: Can you run the query with 'Explain' and post the output.

Comment: id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra

1 SIMPLE L ALL \N \N \N \N 84428
 
1 SIMPLE SE ref ref_id ref_id 4 phdraft.L.ref_id 1 Using index

1 SIMPLE EI eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4 phdraft.SE.extension_id 1 

1 SIMPLE FI ALL \N \N \N \N 717882 Using join buffer

1 SIMPLE C eq_ref ref_id ref_id 4 phdraft.SE.ref_id 1 Using where; Using index

1 SIMPLE F eq_ref ref_id ref_id 4 phdraft.L.ref_id 1 Using where

1 SIMPLE R eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4 phdraft.F.ref_id 1 Using where

Answer (score 2):

Plan A.  Create a `FULLTEXT` index on each set of fields in each of the tables, then use one `MATCH..AGAINST` per table to do the text searching.  But, since the stuff is scattered across 4 tables, do a `UNION` of 4 `SELECTs`, each one has a `MATCH` for one table.  Caveat: It works only on "words" and has other restrictions.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; without it, I can't do much more than this "hand waving".

Here's how you could tackle it:  Think of how to write the `SELECT` to test the field(s) for only 1 table, yet do all the `JOINing` to get the desired result.  Repeat for the other 3 tables.  Then `UNION DISTINCT` the 4 `SELECTs` together.

Plan B:  Build another table with the CONCAT of all those fields in a single column; search that table.

Plan C:  Change the UI.

Plan D:  The `UNION` describe in Plan A *might* be a little faster, even with the awful `LIKE '%text%'`.  This is because the temp table would have less to shovel around.

Plan A will be much faster, but the caveats may prevent use of it.  Plan B won't be much faster.

A `VIEW` us syntactic sugar; not a performance booster.

Answer (score 0):

Please Create A View For your above query and Get data using view its faster than your current query.

Comment: How do I state in the query that if it found '%test%' in farmer_name I don't need to look into field_name if it has '%test%'

Comment: you not  included where in when you creating view.